# Rust: why multiple exclusive borrows are possible for static mut variables in unsafe blocks?

Tags: rust, reference, static, borrow-checker

In Rust, ensuring `mut` borrows are exclusive is a strong invariant. Wanting to circumvent that with `std::mem::transmute` is considered undefined behaviour, because the compiler uses this invariant to apply some optimisations.

Even with `unsafe`, disabling the borrow checker is not possible. However, it seems it is still possible to disabling that for `static mut` variables.

For instance, this does not compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    unsafe {
        let a = &mut s;
        let b = &mut s;
        println!("Result: {a} {b}");  
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
17 |         let a = &mut s;
   |                 ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
18 |         let b = &mut s;
   |                 ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
19 |         println!("{a} {b}");  
   |                   --- first borrow later used here
```

But this code compiles and works fine:

```
static mut s: String = String::new();

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let a = &mut s;
        let b = &mut s;
        println!("Result: {a} {b}");  
    }
}
```

Why this difference?

Is it a kind of legacy that should be removed? Or are there some specific needs or requirements for static variables due to their nature or for code interoperability with C or LLVM, and why?

Comment: You might've noticed that you can't even touch a `static mut` without `unsafe`. That's because it is so inherently unsafe, there are some considerations floating around about removing mutable statics altogether.

Comment: Generally, borrowchecker only works within a single function, and statics are global, so it is straight up impossible to enforce normal borrowing rules for them.

Comment: Oh, wait, I misread your code. You're talking two `&mut`s to the reference to contents of `static s`.

Comment: Taking 2 *exclusive* references to the same memory location is still UB even with statics, but your using `unsafe` tells the compiler, "it's fine, trust me" and so it just compiles.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the reasons accessing `static mut` is unsafe.

As for why the compiler cannot verify that, it is because the borrow checker uses lifetimes to validate the rules that mutable borrows are exclusive. Each variable is assigned a unique lifetime, and the compiler verifies that no-one borrows such lifetime twice. But a borrow of `static` variable always results in a `'static` lifetime (this is necessary to be able to pass it around, there is no other sensible lifetime), and the compiler cannot determine what static variable it is sourced from. This becomes impossible in the general case, too, when the references are just `&'static mut` and we lost all information about where they came from.

This is also one of the reasons why using `static mut` correctly is so hard, and why [you should avoid it at any price](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53639). Prefer `static` with `UnsafeCell` when you need an unsafely mutable static.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Rust compiler is incapable of tracing borrows of `static mut VAR`.
Maybe compiler will catch more such borrowing mistakes in the future,
**BUT** it seems to be **impossible to implement FULL borrow checking for mutable statics**.
That's the reason no one even bothered to do it even for trivial borrowing cases like yours.

Arguably, it would be possible to implement some *case-specific borrow-checks* for cases like yours.
Yet, it's unlikely for an average programmer to introduce *this-specific* bug.
So that's why no one bothered to implement such compile time error, though it would be posible for *this trivial case*.

Comment: "Probably compiler will catch more such borrowing mistakes in the future" I would like to know why you think that. Because that's just, like, _won't happen_ (due to breakage and difficulty).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Rust project doesn't progress linearly but polynomially.  
Imagine: more people start to code in Rust, more people are becoming experts, tools they use also are becoming better, AI starts coding, compiler structure is being changed to facilitate changes.  

So, while currently we don't have time to implement such compilation cases (due to difficulty and little gain), one day it might be easy enough or dangerous enough if lang. changes.
Also, note that removing `static mut` might also be a way to facilitate catching this kind of bugs.

Comment: This is not a matter of "too hard"; this is not even about priorities; this is about the fact that language design is about making trade-offs, and the trade-off for checking some of `static mut` is bad, so bad that the chances it will be chosen are close to zero. Even more importantly, the Rust project avoids breaking user code at (almost) all costs, and any check we'll add will break user code. There is some little chance that there will be lints added (not hard errors), though.

Comment: And about removing `static mut`: I didn't talk about it, but it's certainly an option. Personally, I think this won't happen due to breakage (maybe over an edition), but there was such proposal and the issue is still open: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53639.

Comment: And if you would say "**maybe** compiler will catch more such borrowing mistakes in the future" I wouldn't say a word, but you said "**probably**", and so I wanted to know what you rely on, because from the facts I know the chances are slim.

Comment: Ok, I changed "**probaly**" to "**maybe**".